# How to deal with strings which have a large number of escapes?

Tags: c#, escaping

I'm writing unit tests that are using string comparisons to Assert that operations are successful. The strings that I am working with are encoded with many characters that require escaping. It is a time consuming operation to go through each string and manually add escape characters. Is there a more convenient way of handling these types of strings? I am imagining some C# feature such as `EscapeAll()` but I haven't found one.

Here is an example of a string that requires a tremendous amount of escaping:

```
<td class="name"><span id="153407 - 951"></span><a href=" / statfeed / statfeed.php ? page = mlb / mlbteam & amp; teamid = SAN + FRANCISCO & amp; season = ">951 SAN FRANCISCO GIANTS</a></td><td id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951 - Pitcher" class="pitcher ">(r) cueto, j</td><td class="line">8o20</td><td class="line"><a onclick="openLineMovement('20170630', '335310265', 'MLB'); " href="javascript:; ">8.5o15 / 8.5 / 8.5u20</a></td><td id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951 - Current" class="currentline ">8o20</td><td id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951 - Line" class="line ">+1.5(-194)</td><td id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951" class="score finalscore"><span id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951 - score" class="score first">13</span><span id="ajaxUpdating - 153407 - 951 - progress" class="score progress">Over 8</span></td>";
```

I thought perhaps I could save the string to a file, and read the file in to a string variable, which I could then use to Assert against. But on the other hand, I don't want to hide the string content in a file. It's much better to be able to directly read the string contents within the *.cs file that contains the test fixture. I might be asking for too much?

Comment: I do not see any escape characters in what you have posted `/` is not an escape character.. a single `"\"` however is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you could go to the Resources tab on the project properties page and add string resources.The page lets you give the string a name, value, and comment.  Just paste it as-is into the value column. Then in your code you can refer to it as Resources.MyStringName. As a bonus, hovering over that in the code pops up the value of the string (well long strings get truncated in the pop-up).

Answer (score 1):

> It is a time consuming operation to go through each string and
>   manually add escape characters.

You can use verbose strings

```
@"This is a ""verbose"" string"
```

The double double-quotes (`""`) are the way to escape double-quotes (`"`) in verbose strings. You can
replace these from the original string with double double-quotes using the "Replace" tool of your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use raw strings:

```
@"string with
embedded new line";
```

Answer (score 0):

well even with the verbose strings you will have to double up the quotes. The easiest way is to make a  separate console application which takes input either directly from Standard input or from a file where you can paste the string in and then spit it out in escaped form

```
.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

will do